# Google Cloud Tasks always set HttpMethod to GET when using HttpRequest as payload_type

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-tasks

According to this documentation [ https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks ], one should be able to create tasks with type 'http_request' and 'http_method' set to 'POST', but the behavior is not the expected once the task is always created with method 'GET'.

After having this issue while using the Python Client Library, I've decided to try the API directly and check if it was an issue with the library or with the API itself.

Using the "Try this API" from the product's documentation page [ https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/create ], I've tried to create similar tasks using both http_request and app_engine_http_request types and always setting the http_method to POST.

If I set the request body like this:

```
{
  "task": {
    "appEngineHttpRequest": {
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "relativeUri": "/test",
      "body": "c2hhbGxvdyBub3c="
    }
  }
}
```

...the task is created and the method is POST, like expected. But, if I set the request body to:

```
{
  "task": {
    "httpRequest": {
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "url": "https://httpstat.us/404",
      "body": "c2hhbGxvdyBub3c="
    }
  }
}
```

...the task is created, but with method GET instead of POST.

Here's what I get at my queue:

[image: ![Tasks in the queue.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cxWc43BiWDPOYekAmFMAcMZygG5dYmx6/view?usp=sharing)]

I believe this is a bug, and that's why I'm reporting it here with tag google-apis-explorer as recommended at the support page.

Anyway, if anyone could tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if there's any workaround in the meanwhile I would really appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering outloud .... if the above is your actual request, I don't see any content in the request.   For example, nothing in task.httpRequest.body.  It might be that the environment is trying to be smart and if you submit a REST request with zero payload then it gets converted to a GET request?

Comment: Good point, @Kolban. Unfortunately, that's not the case. I've tried passing body too and the problem remains. But I've updated the question with it for completeness. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank You for this post, this is a bug in the existing Cloud Tasks UI and we are in the process of fixing this bug.

In the meantime the correct HTTP method of the task can be determined by running the following command:

gcloud beta tasks describe

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/tasks/describe

The above command will show the correct HTTP method for the task.

Comment: Hi @Vinod Ramachandran, this is actually great news! As the task is actually being created correctly, this solves my problems. I should have tested it myself, instead I've just accepted that what was in the UI was correct...
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Vinod, I found that the body was not passed properly. 
I tried to log the task I passed:
```
{
  httpRequest: {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    url: 'some_random_url',
    body: 'IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi'
  }
}
```
but the `gcloud beta tasks describe` command gives me this result:
```
createTime: '2019-07-16T15:42:15Z'
dispatchDeadline: 600s
httpRequest:
  headers:
    User-Agent: Google-Cloud-Tasks
  httpMethod: POST
  url: some_random_url
name: task_name
scheduleTime: '2019-07-16T15:42:15.429342Z'
view: BASIC
```
I'm using `@google-cloud/tasks` 1.2.0 npm module